# Spring Security CSRF Token not working with AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, csrf

I have a problem in my spring boot app with the csrf token.

I have a form where I can edit a Person. A Person can have

Let us now imagine that the person has a car and enter this and store it. The next time he wants to delete this car and enter another one. I have created that so that there is a list of all of his cars -- he has the option to remove this from the list. Now I'm starting from these pills and want to send with the corresponding ID to the server a POST. When I try I get a 403 forbidden and I have no idea why.

If I change from POST to GET, then it works.

My JavaScript (taken from this site: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#the-csrfmetatags-tag)

```
var csrfParameter = $("meta[name='_csrf_parameter']").attr("content");
var csrfHeader = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
var csrfToken = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");

// using JQuery to send a non-x-www-form-urlencoded request
var headers = {};
headers[csrfHeader] = csrfToken;
$.ajax({
    url: "./delete/car",
    type: "GET",
    headers: headers,
});

$.ajax({
     url: "./delete/car",
     type: "POST",
     headers: headers,
});
```

My controller methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{login}/delete/car", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView delete(@PathVariable("login") final String login) {
        System.out.println("Stop");
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + WebSecurityConfig.URL_PERSONS_OVERVIEW);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{login}/delete/car", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView deleteInstEmp(@PathVariable("login") final String login) {
        System.out.println("Stop");
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + WebSecurityConfig.URL_PERSONS_OVERVIEW);
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"/{login}/delete/car", method = RequestMethod.GET` this listen to GET requests not POST

Comment: sorry, copy paste error from my site. in my ide it is right

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OK, after strugglin with all that, I get the following result.

I added the `fail` method to the Ajax construct and get the following message:

> "Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': '${_csrf.headerName}' is not a valid HTTP header field name."

the official spring site advises that you have to put this: `<sec:csrfMetaTags />` or from other sources, this: `<meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>` in your html file.

After this, you should be able to access these attributes in your JavaScript, but in my case I get `undefined` and `${_csrf.headerName}`.

A last try was to take the value from the hidden value (chapter 24.5: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#the-csrfmetatags-tag).

Now, I have the following:

```
$(function () {
    var token = $("input[name='_csrf']").val();
    var header = "X-CSRF-TOKEN";
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    });
});

$.ajax({
    url: "./delete/car",
    type: "POST",
    success:function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

With this it works like a charm.

Comment: perfect!! I was even wandering how to put it across. It works. thx!

Answer (score 4):

Another way, you can use the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url : './delete/car',
    headers: {"X-CSRF-TOKEN": $("input[name='_csrf']").val()},
    type : 'POST',
    success : function(result) {
        alert(result.msgDetail);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest you first check if a valid csrf token and the header have been generated using chrome debugger. If not, then have you added the `<sec:csrfMetaTags />` in the `<head>`?(you will need to import the spring security taglibs). If using Apache tiles, you will have to add this at the `<head>` section of the template file being used for the view.
2. If the token is not empty, then in your security-context/configuration file, check if you have disabled csrf security by any chance. By default it is enabled and needs to be for this process to work.