# Spring security lead to error for PUT and POST request through Ajax

Tags: ajax, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a small ajax request which is lead to exeption `PUT http://localhost:8080/carwash/add 405 (Method Not Allowed)`. Can you explaim me where is a problem?

**Ajax request**:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/carwash/add',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'PUT',
        success: function(data) {
            this.setState({});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error('/carwash/add', status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
    })
```

My application is handeling by spring security which has the following configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/logout", "/resources/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/owner").access("hasRole('ROLE_OWNER')")
            .antMatchers("/admin").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/carwash").access("hasRole('ROLE_OWNER')")
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/login?error");
}
```

NB: user that call ajax requst has role 'ROLE_OWNER' and can reach "/owner" and "/carwash" without problem.

Also my controller which is resposible for put request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/carwash/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public void addCarWashPOST(){
    System.out.println("inside addCarWash");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/carwash/add", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public void addCarWashPUT(){
    System.out.println("inside addCarWash");
}
```

All my application is based on spring boot therefore I have also log after this PUT request:

```
DEBUG 12640 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
DEBUG 12640 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing PUT request for [/login]
DEBUG 12640 --- [io-8080-exec-10] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /login
DEBUG 12640 --- [io-8080-exec-10] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PUT' not supported
DEBUG 12640 --- [io-8080-exec-10] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PUT' not supported
DEBUG 12640 --- [io-8080-exec-10] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PUT' not supported
WARN 12640 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'PUT' not supported
DEBUG 12640 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG 12640 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
DEBUG 12640 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing PUT request for [/error]
DEBUG 12640 --- [io-8080-exec-10] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
DEBUG 12640 --- [io-8080-exec-10] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
DEBUG 12640 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor        : Skip CORS processing: request is from same origin
DEBUG 12640 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Written [{timestamp=Wed Sep 14 20:17:20 CEST 2016, status=405, error=Method Not Allowed, exception=org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException, message=Request method 'PUT' not supported, path=/carwash/add}] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@78b6776e]
DEBUG 12640 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG 12640 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

One more interesting issue, if substitute in ajax request type to `POST` the exeption will be different: `/carwash/add parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

The log from spring boot for POST request:

```
DEBUG 13348 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/login]
DEBUG 13348 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /login
DEBUG 13348 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.lang.String biz.controllers.mvc.LoginController.login()]
DEBUG 13348 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/login] is: -1
DEBUG 13348 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver  : No matching bean found for view name 'login'
DEBUG 13348 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'login'; URL [WEB-INF/pages/login.html]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
DEBUG 13348 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to resource [WEB-INF/pages/login.html] in InternalResourceView 'login'
DEBUG 13348 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/WEB-INF/pages/login.html]
DEBUG 13348 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/pages/login.html
DEBUG 13348 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/pages/login.html]
DEBUG 13348 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/WEB-INF/pages/login.html] are [/**]
DEBUG 13348 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/WEB-INF/pages/login.html] are {}
DEBUG 13348 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/WEB-INF/pages/login.html] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@1aa2d29f] and 1 interceptor
DEBUG 13348 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/WEB-INF/pages/login.html] is: -1
DEBUG 13348 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG 13348 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
DEBUG 13348 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

and as I undestand from log, the application cannot `No matching bean found for view name 'login'` how ever I have a controller for `@RequestMapping(value ={"/", "/login"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)` and without problem can open page with link `/login`... What I miss ?

Controller for "/" and "/login"

```
@RequestMapping(value ={"/", "/login"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login() {
    return "login";
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return resolver;
}
```

Comment: Please add the method that have @RequestMapping(value ={"/", "/login"}

Comment: @reos the method was added but the problem in another place, I added `.csrf().disable()` in spring security configuration and put request starts work

Comment: ok, that's beacause you're using csrf protection.

Answer (score 0):

To make an AJAX/JSON request with CSRF enabled you have to pass CSRF token as a HTTP Request Header, not a parameter or other data.

On the page, your meta tags should look like these:

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

Then, prepare values somewhere in the JS code:

```
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
```

Pass the CSRF token as a header:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        async: false,
        url: '/carwash/add',
        data: [your data],
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            // here it is
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        },
        success: function(obj) {
            //  ....
        },
        ....
```

You can see more here

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html

Comment: I coped all your code but this error is appeared: `SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': '${_csrf.headerName}' is not a valid HTTP header field name`

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27834867/spring-security-csrf-token-not-working-with-ajax