# How to fix "403 Forbidden" errors when calling APIs using Python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, http-status-code-403

I needed to parse a [site](http://worldagnetwork.com/), but I got a 403 Forbidden error.

Here is the code:

```
url = 'http://worldagnetwork.com/'
result = requests.get(url)
print(result.content.decode())
```

The output is:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Adding `user-agent` headers works fine for my case. `my_response = requests.get(target_url, headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)`}`

Comment: maybe you need cookie in header, or authorization creds in header:
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Basic {creds_enc}",
    "Cookie":"abcdefgh"
}

Answer (score 371, accepted):

It seems the page rejects `GET` requests that do not identify a `User-Agent`. I visited the page with a browser (Chrome) and copied the `User-Agent` header of the `GET` request (look in the Network tab of the developer tools):

```
import requests
url = 'http://worldagnetwork.com/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(result.content.decode())

# <!doctype html>
# <!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="no-js ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
# <!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="no-js ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
# <!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="no-js ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
# <!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
# ...
```

Comment: You can also just execute `navigator.userAgent` in the Chrome developer console if you are too lazy to look in the network tab :)

Comment: Saved my day, thank you! Almost started to deeply investigate related problems with SSL-certificates but it was kind of dummy anti-robot defense.

Answer (score 34):

Just adding to [Alicia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38489588/2745495):

If you still get a 403 Forbidden error after adding a `user-agent`, you may need to add more headers, such as `referer`:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': '...',
    'referer': 'https://...'
}
```

The headers can be found in the `Network > Headers > Request Headers` of the Developer Tools. (Press `F12` to toggle it.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't found Headers in Network though

Comment: Go to network, refresh the page so there are requests, select any http request (most of them are), then a new box opens which has headers, you should scroll down that list and you'll find request headers

Comment: I tried copying the user agent part to header it didn't work. I have heard on some sites it will never work.

Comment: Where do you find referrer?

Comment: This still didn't work for me FWIW.

Answer (score 3):

If You are the server's owner/admin, and the accepted solution didn't work for You, then try [disabling CSRF protection (link to an SO answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30470844/2101117).

I am using Spring (Java), so the setup requires You to make a `SecurityConfig.java` file containing:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
    // ...
}
```