# Returning 403 Forbidden from simple get but loads okay in browser

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to get some data from a page, but it's returning the error [**403 Forbidden**].

I thought it was the **user agent**, but I tried several user agents and it still returns the error.

I also tried to use the library [fake user-agent](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-useragent) but I did not succeed.

```
with requests.Session() as c:
        url = '...'
        #headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2224.3 Safari/537.36'}
        ua = UserAgent()
        header = {'User-Agent':str(ua.chrome)}
        page = c.get(url, headers=header)
        print page.content
```

When I access the page manually, everything works.

I'm using python 2.7.14 and [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), Any idea?

Comment: Is the URL behind an authwall? From wiki, 403 is result of the web server being configured to deny access to the requested resource by the client.

Comment: @mu無 No, just access the url normally, do not need any authentication

Comment: maybe missing some other header?

Comment: @emecas Truth, maybe that's the point, I'm investigating on the chrome console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python requests. 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489386/python-requests-403-forbidden)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The site could be using anything in the request to trigger the rejection.

So, copy all headers from the request that your browser makes. Then delete them one by one<sup>1</sup> to find out which are essential.

As per [Python requests. 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489386/python-requests-403-forbidden), to add custom headers to the request, do:

```
result = requests.get(url, headers={'header':'value', <etc>})
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>A faster way would be to [delete half of them each time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) instead but that's more complicated since there are probably multiple essential headers</sub>

Answer (score 1):

These all headers I can see for a generic `GET` request that are included by the browser:

```
Host: <URL>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

Try to include all those incrementally in your request (1 by 1) in order to identify which one(s) is/are required for a successful request.

On the other hand, take look  of the tabs: `Cookies` and/or `Security` available in your browser console / developer tools under `Network` option.