# why find object is not iterable?

Tags: python, mongodb, beautifulsoup

I want to crawl the data site.
But something wrong in my code

I want to find why find object is wrong
and search in stack overflow but i can't find what's wrong in this code

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pymongo import MongoClient
import requests
from matplotlib import font_manager, rc

client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
database = client.datadb
collection = database.datacol

page = requests.get("https://www.worlddata.info/average-income.php")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

general_list = soup.find("tr")

#list_of_tr = general_list.find("tr")

for in_each_tr in general_list:
    list_of_td0 = general_list.find_all("td")[0]
    list_of_td1 = general_list.find_all("td")[1]
    general_list = collection.insert_one({"country":list_of_td0.get_text(), "income":list_of_td1.get_text()})


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SAMSUNG/PycharmProjects/simple/data.py", line 18, in <module>
    for in_each_tr in general_list:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What is error you are getting? update the same in question.

Comment: Maybe this just happens to me, but `requests.get("https://www.worlddata.info/average-income.php")` gives me the response [403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403), meaning access to the site is forbidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Website](https://www.worlddata.info/average-income.php) is loading data by ajax request, so you need to use selenium to download dynamic content.

First of install selenium web driver as per your browser.

import selenium web driver

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Download web content

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get('https://www.worlddata.info/average-income.php')
```

Where `"/usr/bin/chromedriver"` webdriver path

Get html content

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
```

Now you will get `tr tag` object

```
general_list = soup.find("tr")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `general_list` is `none` value.

you need to add validation before you do actions on an object.

I'm assuming this address is returning a forbidden error hence the response has no `<tr>`'s.

If you change the address to:

```
page = requests.get("https://www.google.com")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

general_list = soup.find("tr")

for tr in general_list: 
    print(tr)
```

It works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `requests.get("https://www.worlddata.info/average-income.php")` gives [403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) as a response, meaning that access to the web page is forbidden.

I did some googling and found [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38489588). It says that some web pages can reject `GET`requests that do not identify a `User-Agent`.

If you add a header to `requests.get` like so:

```
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get("https://www.worlddata.info/average-income.php", headers=header)
```

Then the response of the `GET` request will be 200, and your code should work as expected.