# request returns 403 in python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I am using beautiful soup to try to parse information from a webpage:

```
url='https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/2-bed-flats-apartments/shortlands-station/?max-bedrooms=&radius=0.5'
req=requests.get(url)
```

req returns `<Response [403]>`

[Python requests. 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489386/python-requests-403-forbidden) suggests there is a user-agent issue, but I cannot find it in my instance.

Are there any suggestions

Comment: I notice the header `cookie: logglytrackingsession=<MY-COOKIE>` being set in the request. The server likely denies requests without a tracking cookie, which get set when loaded in a browser.

Comment: It could be what @JammyDodger mentions, it could be the user agent you mentioned, check the headers your browser sends when accessing the site.

Comment: @luis, it was headers. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In such case so please use headers which include `user-agent`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/2-bed-flats-apartments/shortlands-station/?max-bedrooms=&radius=0.5'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
}

html_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")

print(soup.text)
```

Comment: It isn't always a user agent issue, what to do then?