# How to call a webservice endpoint defined in the same Flask application

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask application which uses the connexion library to create the API.

The application will not just be a web service, but will also be a front end app, consuming its own API rather than making direct database calls.

How do I call, from within a Flask application, an endpoint defined as a web service within the same application?

```
# Create a URL route in our application for "/products"
@app.route('/products')
def products():
    """
    This function just responds to the browser ULR
    localhost:5000/
    :return:        the rendered template 'home.html'
    """
    r = requests.get('api/read/products')
    print(r.text)
    return render_template('products.html', page_title="Regulatory Analytics Home", products="")
```

This is simply generating:

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'api/read/products': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://api/read/products?
```

Changing the path to:

```
r = requests.get('/api/read/products')
```

doesn't work. My products.html file is in a /templates folder, so I tried.

```
r = requests.get('../api/read/products')
```

And this didn't work either, as I assumed I may need a relative path to the root of the site from where the products.html is served from.

Comment: requests expects a url and you seem to be passing a file path. Have you tried passing the url where the flask app will be hosted?

Comment: but thats localhost at the moment, and will change when deployed obviously

Comment: So until that point try passing the localhost url to the requests parameter

Comment: response 403 when I try this. And there is no authentication required.

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489386/python-requests-403-forbidden) you might want to try specifying the http methods that are allowed on your endpoint. I.e methods = get

Comment: Thats got rid of 403, adding a user agent header, thanks.  The issue now is I get a nonsense response.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64467752/getting-incorrect-response-from-flask-using-requests?noredirect=1#comment113994623_64467752