# Getting incorrect response from Flask using requests

Tags: python, flask

I have an endpoint which works fine.  In the browser, I just get a json response when I visit the api, which has no authentication currently.

When I do this:

```
 headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
    products = requests.get('http://myserver.mycompany.net:5000/api/read/products', headers=headers)
    app.app.logger.info("PRODUCTS")
    app.app.logger.info(products.text)
```

My response looks like it is just serving back a html page?!

```
[2020-10-21 17:12:46,760] INFO in api: PRODUCTS
[2020-10-21 17:12:46,761] INFO in api: <!--samlchecks_get.html --><!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Welcome To Zscaler Directory Authentication</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><style type="text/css">body {    background-color: #FFF;    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;    font-size: 12px;    text-align: center;    color: #4B4F54;    overflow: hidden;    margin: 0;}a {    color: #009dd0;    cursor: pointer;    text-decoration: none;}form {    width: 100%;    height: 100%;    margin: 0;    padding: 0;}input {    font-family: Arial;    font-size: 100%;    margin: 0;    width: 100%;    vertical-align: top;    color: #424242;    display: inline-block;    border: none;    padding: 0;    text-align: left;    height: 100%;    width: calc(100% -35px);}table {    margin-top: 10px;    text-align: center;    background-color: white;}table.table-company-logo {    background-color: #e3e3e3;}table.table-upper {    border-radius: 10px;}table.table-lower {    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;    background-color: #f3f3f3;}table.table-field-label {    margin-bottom: 2px;}table.table-field-input div.input-wrapper {    display: block;    border-color: #2a2c30;;    width: inherit;    padding-left: 10px;}table.table-field-input .input-wrapper.disabled {    border-color: #cfd0d1;}table.zsc-company {    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;    background-color: #f3f3f3;}table.zsc-company td {    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;    font-size: 11px;    color: #939393;}.table-hal
```

When I visit the endpoint directly in the browser, I get a json response.

Comment: Probably you have a valid SSO-Session in your Browser. Try in an incognito Window.

Comment: How would that impact the response?

Comment: Same thing happening in incognito....

Comment: Use response.json() not response.text

Comment: doesnt work, just says invalid json response.  Because it is actually returning a different response.  My other post states it may be related to active SSO session in my browser, but it happes in an incognito tab too.