# Logging into a website through requests is returning a 403 error

Tags: python, python-requests

code:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(login_url)
    r = bs(r.content, features='html5lib')
    r = r.find('input', {'name' :'csrfmiddlewaretoken'})
    token = r['value']
    data = {
    'login': 'email',
    'password': 'password',
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': token
    }
    response = s.post(login_url, data)
```

`response.ok` returns false and `response.status_code` returns 403. Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: probably the token should not be a part of the body, instead should be set as a header {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken}} or in cookies (depends on the middleware of the website)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489386/python-requests-403-forbidden

Comment: Ok yeah I fixed it, I just needed to add headers