# Python requests response 403 forbidden

Tags: python, python-requests, http-status-code-403, python-requests-html

So I am trying to scrape this website: https://www.auto24.ee
I was able to scrape data from it without any problems, but today it gives me "Response 403". I tried using proxies, passing more information to headers, but unfortunately nothing seems to work. I could not find any solution on the internet, I tried different methods.
The code that worked before without any problems:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36',
}

page = requests.get("https://www.auto24.ee/", headers=headers)

print(page)
```

Comment: I don’t think you need to spoof the user-agent. Just make sure you avoid the resources specified by `/robots.txt` on that site

Comment: See this [Python requests. 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38489588/4694757)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code here

```python
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get("https://www.auto24.ee/", headers=headers)
print(page.text)
```

Always will get something as the following

```html
 <div class="cf-section cf-wrapper">
        <div class="cf-columns two">
          <div class="cf-column">
            <h2 data-translate="why_captcha_headline">Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA?</h2>

            <p data-translate="why_captcha_detail">Completing the CAPTCHA proves you are a human and gives you temporary access to the web property.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="cf-column">
            <h2 data-translate="resolve_captcha_headline">What can I do to prevent this in the future?</h2>


            <p data-translate="resolve_captcha_antivirus">If you are on a personal connection, like at home, you can 
run an anti-virus scan on your device to make sure it is not infected with malware.</p>
```

The website is protected by CloudFlare. By standard means, there is minimal chance of being able to access the WebSite through automation such as requests or selenium. You are seeing 403 since your client is detected as a robot. There may be some arbitrary methods to bypass CloudFlare that could be found elsewhere, but the WebSite is working as intended. There must be a ton of data submitted through headers and cookies that show your request is valid, and since you are simply submitting only a user agent, CloudFlare is triggered. Simply spoofing another user-agent is not even close to enough to not trigger a captcha, CloudFlare checks for MANY things.

I suggest you look at selenium [here](https://www.selenium.dev/) since it simulates a real browser, or research guides to (possibly?) bypass Cloudflare with requests.

**Update**
Found 2 python libraries cloudscraper and cfscrape. Both are not usable for this site since it uses cloudflare v2 unless you pay for a premium version.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did not realize it myself. Atleast now I know the cause. Unfortunately it´s not easy to develop a captcha solver for this one.