# Newbie, Scraping Issue , FUTBIN web scraping issue

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to web scraping and i was trying to scrape through FUTBIN (FUT 22) player database
"https://www.futbin.com/players" . My code is below and I don't know why if can't get any sort of results from the FUTBIN page but was successful in other webpages like IMDB.

### CODE :`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = requests.get("https://www.futbin.com/players")
src = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, features="html.parser")

results = soup.find("a", class_="player_name_players_table get-tp`enter code here`")
print(results)
```

Comment: Website is protected by Cloudflare - Check your `soup` if the expected content is available.

Comment: Yes it stops on cloudflare challenge: <title>Please Wait... | Cloudflare</title> as mentioned HedgeHog. It works with playwright i just tried it. PW use real browser and you can bypass. Here you have playwright documentation https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro. I

Comment: This post may solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70369790/python-requests-response-403-forbidden