# read data from chrome console to python

Tags: python, google-chrome, web-scraping, xpath, python-requests

`I have a code in python to read xpath from a website (https://www.op.gg/summoners/kr/Hide%20on%20bush)

```
import requests
import lxml.html as html
import pandas as pd

url_padre = "https://www.op.gg/summoners/br/tercermundista"

link_farm = '//div[@class="stats"]//div[@class="cs"]'

r = requests.get(url_padre) 

home=r.content.decode("utf-8") 

parser=html.fromstring(home) 
farm=parser.xpath(link_farm) 

print(farm)`
```

this code print "[]"

but when in the console chrome put this xpath: $x('//div[@class="stats"]//div[@class="cs"]').map(x=>x.innerText), this print the numbers i want, but my python code dont do it
What is the mistake?

i want a code to solve my mistake

--------------------------edit---------------------------

---

```
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\GCO\Desktop\Analisis de datos\borradores\fsdfs.ipynb Cell 2 in 3
      1 from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
----> 3 with sync_playwright() as p, p.chromium.launch() as browser:
      4     page = browser.new_page()
      5     page.goto("https://www.op.gg/summoners/kr/Hide%20on%20bush", timeout=10000)

File c:\Users\GCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_context_manager.py:47, in PlaywrightContextManager.__enter__(self)
     45             self._own_loop = True
     46         if self._loop.is_running():
---> 47             raise Error(
     48                 """It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
     49 Please use the Async API instead."""
     50             )
     52         # In Python 3.7, asyncio.Process.wait() hangs because it does not use ThreadedChildWatcher
     53         # which is used in Python 3.8+. This is unix specific and also takes care about
     54         # cleaning up zombie processes. See https://bugs.python.org/issue35621
     55         if (
     56             sys.version_info[0] == 3
     57             and sys.version_info[1] == 7
     58             and sys.platform != "win32"
     59             and isinstance(asyncio.get_child_watcher(), asyncio.SafeChildWatcher)
     60         ):

Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
Please use the Async API instead.
```

Comment: please add contents of `print(home)` to your question. I believe you do not succeed with the request itself

Comment: `Request blocked.` says the page. Cloudronft might be protecting itself from automation. It could be possible to workaround that but I believe it's not easy

Comment: There is a workaround, but I still cannot get elements using your xpath: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70370164/17200418

Comment: I think that contents that you are trying to get are dynamically loaded, so may be you need to try some more advanced parsing tool. You can try `selenium` or `playwright`.

Comment: i can do it with this page too "https://u.gg/lol/profile/kr/hide%20on%20bush/overview", and change the code for: ('//div[@class="post-stats"]//div[@class="cs"]'), and r.status_code = 200, but the answer is the same... print me "[]"

Comment: Actually this u.gg site is working the same way here. Have a look at my answer below. Using `playwright` is much slower but I believe it will fit better for you. Especially in case you will want to grab more data scrolling the page down.

Comment: ok bro! i will try, thank u so much for ur answer, now im gonna try to use it for my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you can not get dynamically generated content using `requests`.

Here is solution using `playwright` which can load whole page before parsing.

1. Install playwright using `pip install playwright`
2. Install browser and dependencies using `playwright install chromium --with-deps`
3. Run following code

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p, p.chromium.launch() as browser:
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://www.op.gg/summoners/kr/Hide%20on%20bush", timeout=10000)
    selector = "//div[@class='stats']//div[@class='cs']/div"
    cs_stats = page.query_selector_all(selector)
    print(len(cs_stats), [cs.inner_text() for cs in cs_stats])
```

If you want to stick with `lxml` as parsing tool you can use following code:

```
from lxml import html
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p, p.chromium.launch() as browser:
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://www.op.gg/summoners/kr/Hide%20on%20bush", timeout=10000)
    selector = "//div[@class='stats']//div[@class='cs']/div"
    c = page.content()
    parser = html.fromstring(c)
    farm = parser.xpath(selector)
    print(len(farm), [cs.text for cs in farm])
```

**P.S.**

Also I have noticed that op.gg use pretty simple HTTP requests that do not need authorization. You can find desired info using this code:

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = "https://op.gg/api/v1.0/internal/bypass/games/kr/summoners/4b4tvMrpRRDLvXAiQ_Vmh5yMOsD0R3GPGTUVfIanp1Httg?&limit=20"
r = urlopen(url)
games = json.load(r).get("data", [])
print(games)
```

`games` is a list of dicts that stores all info you need. CS stats are stored in list element under following keys: `games[0]["myData"]["stats"]["minion_kill"]`

The only difficult thing here is to find how to get `summoner_id` for desired user (which is `4b4tvMrpRRDLvXAiQ_Vmh5yMOsD0R3GPGTUVfIanp1Httg` in your example)

Comment: hello man, i used your code but it didnt work, i put the error in the code above                          pd: i installed playwright in vscode and Chromium in the cmd console because i couldn't do it in vscode

Comment: I can see .ipynb in your path, so you are using Jupiter notebooks. Have a look at this answer to make playwright code async: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71702599/17200418

Comment: well i can use .py too hahaha, its works man!! thanks! i have a lot to learn, i hope to get what i want from the page modifing this code

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example how to load the data from external URL and compute the CS value:

```py
import re
import requests


url = "https://www.op.gg/summoners/kr/Hide%20on%20bush"
api_url = "https://op.gg/api/v1.0/internal/bypass/games/kr/summoners/{summoner_id}?=&limit=20&hl=en_US&game_type=total"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0"
}

html_doc = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
summoner_id = re.search(r'"summoner_id":"(.*?)"', html_doc).group(1)

data = requests.get(api_url.format(summoner_id=summoner_id), headers=headers).json()

for d in data["data"]:
    stats = d["myData"]["stats"]
    kills = (
        stats["minion_kill"]
        + stats["neutral_minion_kill_team_jungle"]
        + stats["neutral_minion_kill_enemy_jungle"]
        + stats["neutral_minion_kill"]
    )
    cs = kills / (d['game_length_second'] / 60)
    print(f'{cs=:.1f}')
```

Prints:

```
cs=6.7
cs=8.5
cs=8.2
cs=1.4
cs=7.3
cs=8.5
cs=6.8
cs=7.7
cs=8.7
cs=8.8
cs=5.6
cs=9.9
cs=7.0
cs=9.6
cs=9.7
cs=5.0
cs=7.5
cs=9.2
cs=9.0
cs=7.9
```