# Scraping data from a particular pdf hosted online

Tags: python, web-scraping, pdf-scraping

I am trying to scrap data from series of pdfs hosted online
The code I am using is-

```
import fitz
import requests
import io
import re

url_pdf = ["https://wcsecure.weblink.com.au/pdf/ASN/02528656.pdf"]
for url in url_pdf:
    # Download the PDF file
    print(url)
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        pdf_file = io.BytesIO(response.content)

        # Extract the text content of the PDF file
        pdf_reader = fitz.open(stream=pdf_file.read(), filetype="pdf")
        text_content = ''
        for page in range(pdf_reader.page_count):
            text_content += pdf_reader.load_page(page).get_text()

    except:
        print("Fail")


print(text_content)
```

However it fails for several pdfs such as-
https://livent.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/Livent_2021SustainabilityReport-English.pdf

https://www.minviro.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Shifting-the-lens.pdf

etc. What could be the reason and how to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489386/python-requests-403-forbidden

Comment: For the first URL I am seeing response 403 (forbidden). The second has response 406 (not acceptable). I would argue, these are the reasons ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be useful to see information on the error by printing out the exceptions, e.g. with:

```
    except Exception:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()
        continue
```

Alternatively, simply remove the `try:` and `except ...:` statements from your code, and Python will show exception information for you as it terminates.

This information might be useful in figuring out what is going wrong.